# Fire a function when data gets read by a unique user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I fire a function once data gets read by a unique user?

Cloud Functions has a parameter called onWrite. Is there something like onRead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to trigger Cloud Functions when a user reads data.